# Where is Kalápagrama associated with king Maru and Devapi?

Tags: vishnu-purana, chandravansh, suryavansh

[Vishnu Purana: Book IV: Chapter IV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp096.htm):

> The son of this saintly king was Pushya; his son was Dhruvasandhi; his son was Sudarśana; his son was Agnivarńa; his son was Śíghra; his son was **Maru, who through the power of devotion (Yoga) is still living in the village called Kalápa, and in a future age will be the restorer of the Kshatriya race in the solar dynasty**. Maru had a son named Prasuśruta; his son was Susandhi; his son was Amarsha; his son was Mahaswat; his son was Viśrutavat; and his son was Vrihadbala, who was killed in the great war by Abhimanyu, the son of Anjuna.

[Vishnu Purana: Book IV: Chapter XXIV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp117.htm):

> **Two persons, Devápi of the race of Puru, and Maru of the family of Ikshwáku, through the force of devotion continue alive throughout the whole four ages, residing at the village of Kalápa**: they will return hither in the beginning of the Krita age, and, becoming members of the family of the Manu, give origin to the Kshatriya dynasties. In this manner the earth is possessed through every series of the three first ages, the Krita, Treta, and Dwápara, by the sons of the Manu; and some remain in the Kali age, to serve as the rudiments of renewed generations, in the same way as Devápi and Maru are still in existence.

Devapi was elder brother of Kuru king Śántanu (Bhishma Pitamaha's father). ~[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devapi) & [VP.4.20](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp113.htm)

The text marked in bold mentions that the king Maru and Devapi are living in Kalápagrama and will be the restorers of the Kshatriya race in the solar and lunar dynasty respectively in future age. Where is this village Kalápa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This village (-cum-forest) is said to be near Badarikāśrama in the present-day Indian state of Uttarakhand.

This may be attested from the footnotes of two different translators.

##### 1. Translator G.V. Tagare in the Brahmāṇḍa -Purāṇa in [1.1.164](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc243151.html#note-e-125403)

> Footnote [34]: **A village in the Himalayas near Badarikāśrama** where Maru and Devāpi, the last kings of the Solar and Lunar races respectively performed penance to reappear again as kings of Ayodhyā and Hastinapur after Kalki.—De, p. 74.

##### 2. Śrīla Prabhupada in the  Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam Purāṇa: [ŚB 10.87.7](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/87/7/?query=kal%C4%81pa#bb74985)

> Synonyms
>
> tatra — there; upaviṣṭam — sitting; ṛṣibhiḥ — by sages;
> **kalāpa-grāma — in the village Kalāpa (nearby Badarikāśrama)**; vāsibhiḥ
> — who resided; parītam — surrounded; praṇataḥ — bowing down; apṛcchat
> — he asked; idam eva — this same (question); kuru-udvaha — O most
> eminent of the Kurus.

---

- The translator of the Viṣṇu Purāṇa - H.H. Wilson also notes this place to be around the Himalayan regions in his translation of Visnu Purana [3.16.17](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115993.html)

> In former times, O king of the earth! this song of the Pitris was
> heard by Ikṣvāku, the son of Manu, **in the groves of Kalāpa (on the
> skirts of the Himālaya mountains)**....