# Which Gods and other immortals are living on the Earth today?

Tags: gods, earth, immortality

Lord Shiva is said to live on Mount Kailash which is said to be in Tibet.

People claim to have sighted Ashwatthama in northern India.

Any others?

Comment: Sri Vasudeva in the form of Koorma is still living in the ocean and the sound of beach is said to be his sound of his breathing, Markandeya Mahamuni And Offcourse God is Omnipresent

Answer (score 3):

There are many gods and immortals said to be living currently on Earth.

An inexhaustible list maybe as follows.

- 1. God Adi Varaha

As discussed in Skandamahāpurāṇa 2.1.3, in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2086/17833)

> Varaha (Vishnu's manifestation) lives on the western bank of the Svāmipuṣkariṇī lake near Tirupati Kshetra.

---

- 2. God Parshurama

As discussed [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18316/17833)

> SB 9.16.26
>
> **Lord Paraśurāma still lives as an intelligent brāhmaṇa in the
> mountainous country known as Mahendra.**

---

- 3. &. 4. God Hanuman & Lankapati Vibhishana

As discussed in [this Answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27176/17833)

> SB 5.19.1
>
> Srî S'uka said: '**In the land of Kimpurusha the supreme and greatest
> devotee Hanumân delighting in service at His feet is together** with the
> people...

&

As discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27176/17833)

Both Hanumana and Vibhishana are supposed to live on earth till the history of Lord Rama remains current:

> Chapter 121, Uttarakanda, Valmiki Ramayana
>
> Rama then said to Vibhishana the king of Rakshasas: **As long as
> people shall breathe, O Vibhishana, O highly powerful lord of
> Rakshasas, thou shalt preserve thy body in Lanka.**
>
> As long as the moon, the sun and the earth shall exist and as long as
> my story shall remain current, thy kingdom shall be in existence.
>
> .....
>
> Having thus addressed the king of Rakshasas always obeying Raghava s
> command, Kakuthstha **said to Hanuman "It is settled that thou shalt
> live forever, do thou, now observe thy promise. As long as my history
> shall run current in this world do thou at my command live happily.**"
> Being thus addressed by the high souled Raghava Hanuman attained to
> great delight and said: As long as the sacred theme shall pass current
> in this world I shall live here carrying out thy commands.

---

- 5. & 6. King Maru & Devapi, as discussed [in this QnA](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/48746/where-is-kal%C3%A1pagrama-associated-with-king-maru-and-devapi/50720#50720):

> Vishnu Purana: Book IV: Chapter IV:
>
> Maru, who through the power of
> devotion (Yoga) is still living in the village called Kalápa, and in a
> future age will be the restorer of the Kshatriya race in the solar
> dynasty

On a side note, Asura king Mahabali lives in the Sutala-loka, as discussed in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37055/17833)

---

#### To conclude:

God Varaha, Parshurama, Hanuman, Vibhishana, King Maru and Devapi, and many others are are said to live presently on Earth in the Kaliyuga.

<sup>Note that this list is not an exhaustive list.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Bhagwan is said to be omnipresent, and that makes this question not correct, Sri Tyagaraja swamigal said that Koorma is still living in the beach and the sound of beach is the sound of him breathing, Krishna does live in the hearts of his devotees and this was the reason Kulasekara Alwar used to worship devotees rather than Bhagwan. So all of this shows God is still with us today!. Also people say they have spotted Hanuman chanting Ram in the himalayas. Markandeya Maharishi who has blessings of Lord Shiva has no death so he too is with us right now

> Even Vyasa Maharishi, Aswathama, Bhalichakravathy, Hanuman, Bhagwan Parshuram, Vibhisa, Kripacharya are all immortals with respect to Padma Puran

Comment: but gods also have abodes like vaikuntha,goloka etc. which are not on earth.

Comment: Off course he does stay in his abode but he is omnipresent too and understanding him is very much difficult than Calculus!

Answer (score 1):

अश्वत्थामा बलिर्व्यासो हनुमानश्च विभीषणः।
कृपः परशुरामश्च सप्तैते चिरंजीविनः।।

Padmapuran

There are 7 immortals or chiranjeevi present on the earth.
1 ashwatthama
2 King Bali (satyug)
3 ved vyas
4 hanuman
5 vibhishan
6 kripacharya
7 parshuram

Answer (score 0):

Bhagwan Parashuram

Hanuman ji

Kripacharya (who gave pandavas and kauravas Thier early education)

Maharishi **VEDA VYASA** (who wrote Mahabharata)

Comment: any scriptural backing for these examples?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).